# How to track the progress of the content of the file using either html, jquery or perl?

Tags: jquery, html, perl

I am using CGI + HTML to make a web application which runs external Perl program, for that I am using the system. This program takes approximately 60 min to complete and each step is recorded in a file. I would like to show those steps on the web browser as a real-time. I tried using the following command:

```
system('tail -f ' $filename);
```

This command works finee, however, it does not exist to show the footer. I tried -

```
'tail -fq $filename'
```

I appreciate any suggestion or comment.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make the page reload itself every 20s? Make AJAX calls to get the progress details?

Answer (score 0):

My rather crude solution that I use for many years in shell CGI scripts is very simple: I use two scripts: first CGI script launches the process in background with nohup redirected to some logfile and immediately prints simple HTML to redirect browser to second script:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='/cgi-bin/showprogress.cgi'" />
    </head>
</html>
```

The browser is redirected to showprogress.cgi, then showprogress.cgi prints tail -n20 logfile as HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;URL='/cgi-bin/showprogress.cgi'" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>
            [last 20 logfile lines]
        </pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

No javascript or anything complicated, meta refresh works fine.

Don't use tail -f, it won't work.